# Make API responses work with Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm making some play projects with OPENAI API endpoint using a very simple Flutter Project using Dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'dart:io';

import 'package:langchain/langchain.dart';
import 'package:langchain_chroma/langchain_chroma.dart';
import 'package:langchain_openai/langchain_openai.dart';

void main() async {
  const openaiApiKey = 'OPEN_AI_KEY';
  final embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(apiKey: openaiApiKey);
  final vectorStore = Chroma(embeddings: embeddings);

  // Add documents to the vector store
  await vectorStore.addDocuments(
    documents: const [
      Document(
        id: '1',
        pageContent: 'The cat sat on the mat',
        metadata: {'cat': 'animal'},
      ),
      Document(
        id: '2',
        pageContent: 'The dog chased the ball.',
        metadata: {'cat': 'animal'},
      ),
      Document(
        id: '3',
        pageContent: 'The boy ate the apple.',
        metadata: {'cat': 'person'},
      ),
 
    ],
  );

  // Query the vector store
  final res = await vectorStore.similaritySearch(
    query: 'What are they eating?',
    config: const ChromaSimilaritySearch(
      k: 2,
      scoreThreshold: 0.4,
      where: {'cat': 'person'},
    ),
  );
  print(res);
}
```

Here is my Manifest.xml configuration :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:label="kurai_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is my network-security-config library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

The way I'm running the app is using an emulator **Pixel 3a API 34** and I have activated the wireless debug mode.

However I'm sure I'm missing something because I can't pair my PC with the Android emulated device that actually seems to be connected to the internet via Android Wifi.

When I launch the pair command after prompting the PAIR CODE request I get a bad response. I think that the problem is that my PC has an IP of class 192.168.X.X and Android device has an IP of class 10.0.2.X but even using a Charles proxy I couldn't find a way to pair the device.

The second problem that I have is that if I run the app I get this response below :

```
V/studio.transport(28105): Agent handling command (id:8 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:28105.
[OpenAI] api key set to ****jaZGJTVzDa
[OpenAI] accessing endpoint: /embeddings
[OpenAI] starting request to https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings
[OpenAI] request to https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings finished with status code 200
[OpenAI] starting decoding response body
[OpenAI] response body decoded successfully
[OpenAI] request finished successfully
E/flutter (28105): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ChromaApiClientException({
E/flutter (28105):   "uri": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/collections",
E/flutter (28105):   "method": "POST",
E/flutter (28105):   "code": null,
E/flutter (28105):   "message": "Response error",
E/flutter (28105):   "body": "ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 54926, uri=http://localhost:8000/api/v1/collections"
E/flutter (28105): })
```

I have tried a lot of suggestions but there are too many things to look at and I'm really lost. Can someone explain me the procedure to do solve those issues? By the way I'm working on W10.

Thank you